# ActiveMQ: Sending the same message to multiple destinations

Tags: xml, jms, activemq-classic

I'm using ativemq 5.12.0 and I've a producer `P`.
I would send the same message `M` to multiple destinations, for example queues `Q1` and `Q1_BACKUP`, in order to read the same message at the same moment from `Q1` and `Q1_BACKUP`.
How can I achieve this in ActiveMQ?
Could you provide me simple XML configuration of producer and eventually consumer?
I started from [here](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) (Composite Destinations). Could be this the correct approach or are there others?

Comment: What's the use case here?  Because even if you publish the same message at the same time to multiple destinations (whether within the same server or spanning servers) there's no guarantee they'll be processed at the same time.